# Adobe Flash FileReference Save method - save as a file type in Windows 7

Tags: flash, apache-flex, windows-7, save, filereference

I am using FileReference.save to save a jpg to the user's computer.  In Windows 7, I pass in 'test.jpg' as the file name to be saved but only 'test' appears in the file save dialogue ('test.jpg' appears as the file name in Windows Vista).  So, unless the user manually adds the .jpg extension, Windows 7 does not know it is a jpeg file since it is just being saved as 'test'.  I'd like to be able to pass the .jpg extension for the user but Windows 7 seems to be stripping the file extension from the file name that is passed to the file save dialogue.

```
fr = new FileReference();
fr.save(imgByteArray, 'test.jpg');
```

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but are you the Windows setting to hide extensions for known file types is unchecked?  ( It is checked by default ).    Are you personally testing this, or is it feedback from the user?  If the latter, are you sure the user didn't change or remove the file extension before saving?

Comment: I'm personally testing this.  I was using Windows Vista and recently upgraded to Windows 7 and noticed this.  It appears to be an issue with the file save dialogue.  I am passing in 'test.jpg' as the file name to be saved but only 'test' is appearing as the file name to be saved.  I can, as the user, add the .jpg manually in the file save dialogue and it's fine but I want to be able to pass in the .jpg extension for the user.

Comment: I'm going to edit the original post.  It's an issue of 'test.jpg' being the file name passed to the file save dialogue but only 'test' appearing as the file name to be saved.  So Windows has no idea what file type it is unless the user manually adds the .jpg file extension.

Comment: @Steven the problem is exactly what Flextras describes this issue occurs when you have hide extensions for known file types selected, go to an explorer window (My Computer will work) hit alt, go to tools menu go to folder options click the second tab, in the list of checkboxes find Hide Extensions of known Filetypes uncheck that.  Now you'll see the file extension, honestly I'd still probably consider this a bug but it actually saves with the extension it's just hiding it from your view.

Comment: I would answer but I think this one is @www.Flextras.com if he wants to post it as an answer.

Comment: @shaunhusain I was just guessing; If you did the research; post it up.

Comment: Is anybody aware of a workaround for this?  Most of our users have file extensions hidden, and they end up having to get help from customer support when they can't open the file they downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the issue is just that the OS is hiding the extensions from you.  To fix it:

1. Click **Start Menu**
2. Click **My Computer**
3. With my computer window having focus (click on it to be sure) hit the **Alt** key this will give you the older style menus.
4. Click the **Tools** menu go down to **Folder options...**
5. In the window that pops up click the second tab at the top called **View**.
6. In the list of checkboxes at the bottom uncheck the **Hide extension for known file types** box.
7. Hit **OK**
8. Run your Flex program again

Alternative to steps 1 and 2 you can hit **WinKey+E** to get an explorer window.

Yay for technical writing 101.

When you do a save, browse, or download, action the dialog that's opened is OS dependent and so is treated with settings applied to the OS by the user.  If you're in the context of AIR you can save directly without the dialogs using the FileStream class.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue and corrected it.  I guess the only thing to do is to tell the user to make sure to save the file with a .jpg extension.